# webapps folder doesn't contain or display html files

Tags: java, tomcat, webserver, war

I am doing this for the first time. I have a maven project. I added a tomcat servlet which runs fine. A message comes up saying "Listening for messages".

But I am not able to see anything at the localhost:8080. I see the tomcat manager, I see my project (because I generated a war file and put it there) but inside the webapps folder for this project there are no html files and when I visit the project address or an address for a specific html file e.g. localhost:8080/projectName/file.html as per all the examples I read/watch, I get a 404. I know there are other posts on here about this, I have either tried their solutions or I don't understand them.

Does anyone know what to check next? I have been trying to get a servlet running for hours and done a lot of searching, I feel like this is the final hurdle so I would love some help. please!

EDIT: Even though I did get the html to display at the localhost:8080, I'm not sure this was what I wanted. It just displays a static webpage. I want to be able to see the webpages as I'm developing them. E.g. if I edit the HTML I want to see the changes.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Arrgh, this is the second time I've posted a question after hours of trying and then found the solution on my own in about 2 minutes.

In case anyone else needs to know, the solution was to generate the war file in the same folder as the actual html files!